# Searching a cell for a particular string, outputting a different string in a different cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm looking to search for a string in a cell, and then output a different string of text into another cell. Example: Cell A1 contains the string "370904RV". I'd like to search for "37" and if true, output "Performance" into cell B1.

Note: Not every entry in my range will be searching for the first two characters. Eventually, I will expand the code to then look for (in the example) "09", outputting "0.9 inches" and so forth

Edit: Looking for a VBA function as the output cell may be different (example: Cell A1 contains "370904RV" and A2 contains "370906RV". I want to search through $A range, and output something in $B that could vary. So searching and finding "04" will output 0.4 inches into B1, but searching and finding "06" will output 0.6 inches into B2.

Comment: You could use a lookup table, or, in VBA, possibly a `Select Case` construct. Without more specific rules than what you have chosen to share, hard to provide you with anything other than general suggestions. Easy to do for your specific examples; hard to provide something that you will be able to generalize to whatever your real situation might be, especially since your knowledge of VBA is apparently limited.

Answer (score 1):

Set cell B1 to be `=if(find("37",A1),"Performance","")`

Comment: I edited my original to hopefully explain a bit better. Your line would work fine but as I go further in this project, I'll be looking to output quite a few different strings.

Comment: [Range.Find method (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)  Should give you a good jump start.